# Как заставить работать imagick - пути

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

> Такой путь видит

$image = new Imagick("C:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/img/img.jpg");

> Такой путь НЕ ВИДИТ

$image = new Imagick('img/img.jpg');

и почему не грузится то что после header() - выводится только это

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/">
```

---

```
<?phpheader('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('img/img.jpg');

$image->adaptiveBlurImage(5,3);
echo $image;
// $image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'img/img.jpg');
// // Если в качестве ширины или высоты передан 0,
// // то сохраняется соотношение сторон

 echo "<div>wtfwtfwtfwtf</div>;

?>
```

Comment: Вы заметили, что среди ошибок есть сообщение о несуществующем файле `img/img.jpg`? Для начала проверьте путь к картинке

Comment: пробелы перед `<?php` - если они есть в коде, уберите. Это может убрать ошибку `headers already sent `

Comment: @cyadvert , убрал пробелы- а потом после header никакие dom элементы не грузятся,

Comment: Задайте путь к картинке вот так: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img/img.jpg'`. Вы слеш забыли.

Comment: @VenZell спасибо. задал. однако почему после header ничего нет

Comment: @Stein_, проверьте, нет ли других ошибок. Вы приводили цитату в самой первой версии сообщения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/">
```

Это всего лишь попытка браузеров с движком webkit отобразить картинку.
Вы передаете заголовок `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');`, помните?

Дальше ничего не выводится из-за фатальной ошибки.

Вот цитата из первой версии вашего сообщения:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'unable to open image `img/img.jpg': No such file or directory

Картинки по указанному пути не существует. В вашем вопросе уже есть почти правильное решение:

```
// $image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'img/img.jpg');
```

Единственное, о чем вы забыли, так это добавить слеш. Правильно будет вот так, учитывая, что у вас Windows и OpenServer:

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/img.jpg');
```

Или независимый от платформы вариант:

```
$image = new Imagick($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img.jpg');
```

Comment: А еще можно все слеши заменить на `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` константу, которая будет отдавать нужные слеши в зависимости от системы.

Comment: Да, можно, я это указывал в комментарии. Пожалуй, перенесу и сюда, спасибо

Comment: @VenZell но как совместить и новый вывод информации (новые ДОМ элементы) и  header

Comment: @Stein_, разделите обязанности. Файл, где нужен html с одним заголовком, а файл с картинкой - с другим. Где будет html просто укажите ссылку на php с картинкой в src тега img. Например, так: `<img src="/img.php">`. Заголовок `Content-type: image/jpeg` не подразумевает наличия в выводе html

Comment: @VenZell наверное единственное логическое решение)

Comment: @Stein_, если вас устроил мой ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его верным